# Burninate [sections] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Just came upon a HTML question that had [sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sections) as a tag. It kind of got me interested, since I couldn't really think that sections would have been a tag assigned for HTML.

I went and searched around the (< 300) questions tagged with it a little and it basically ranges from HTML, arrays, databases, design, files and more stuff. So it doesn't seem to really fall under one category.

There seems to be quite a few questions related with "UITableView" though. I was wondering if this tag should be burninated, or perhaps some wiki should be added (not one that I could think of).

In any case it doesn't seem very meaningful and looks ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 3):

Too vague to be useful. (i.4 in "[when to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)") Also ambiguous (i.1) 'cuz it means both a part of something and a geometrical concept.

In questions, it needs to be either deleted or replaced with more area-specific terms.

Due to the word's inherent ambiguity, blacklisted, too -- the ambiguity will prevent it from ever being a useful tag.

Some common replacements that I see:

- with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5): -> [html5-section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-section)
- with [uitableiew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableiew) or [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift): -> [uitableview-section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview-section)
- with [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays): -> [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slice)